# Sphinx Search - Returning unique results only possible?

Tags: php, unique, sphinx, distinct

We use sphinxsearch for a number of our web services.

We were wondering if there is any way to have it return only unique results?

As the case is now, we sometimes get results like "title matched" and "title matched" since our sphinx database **does** have some duplicate entries.

Is there a way to instruct sphinx to return only unique results?

We are using sphinx 2.0.4 and accessing it via the php pecl extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create integer attribute by the titles using CRC32 like CRC32(title) as title_crc.
To find only unique titles group search by this attribute - using SetGroupBy function.

Comment: this is a rather elegant way of doing things. big ups!

Answer (score 0):

If case you use postgresql, you can edit sql_query in sphinx.conf: select distinct id, .. from table

Or you, can filter in your php code